# Store and retrieve the content on page postback.

Tags: asp.net

I want to store the content in a format like this, and be able to retrieve after page postback. Can I use a Hidden field? If so which datatype (not string?) Stringbuilder ?

```
    <b>Email Template:</b> UserAssignment
    <b>TO:</b> manojp.nayak@gmail.com<b>CC:</b> 
    <b>FROM:</b>admin@gmail.com <b>SUBJECT:</b>Task Assignment Project Activity  has been assigned to you.

    <b>BODY:</b> Deliverable Information :
    Test Deliverable 01 Test Issue 01   


    Project Activity  assigned by: Admin at: 2013-01-29 7:50 PM

    Automated Email Notification. Do not reply.

    Email Comments: 123test

    <b>FILES:</b>
```

Comment: Do you have a textbox for each of this fields? Do you want to do this via Javascript? I would say its easier to do on your codebehind, using a stringbuilder. What are you thinking to do with this text afterwards?

Comment: I want to do it in codebehingd only .. Like the above give format I have many formats. Later on in a different function i want to retieve each format one by one .. and put it into a panel for display.

Comment: Will you be storing all of the formats in a database? One easy way to accomplish this is trough Session variables, you could store in session each one of the formats, and then put them in a panel whenever you're ready. Altough this comes with a caveat: Remember its session, so it might use a lot of memory on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.
you can use something like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_data" runat="server" />
```

And from code behind on your event you can save the value you want in here with something like:

```
HiddenField_data.Value = @"<b>Email Template:</b> UserAssignment
    <b>TO:</b> manojp.nayak@gmail.com<b>CC:</b> 
    <b>FROM:</b>admin@gmail.com <b>SUBJECT:</b>Task Assignment Project Activity  has been assigned to you.

    <b>BODY:</b> Deliverable Information :
    Test Deliverable 01 Test Issue 01   


    Project Activity  assigned by: Admin at: 2013-01-29 7:50 PM

    Automated Email Notification. Do not reply.

    Email Comments: 123test

    <b>FILES:</b> ";
```

Comment: This would only work if you disable Request Validation; otherwise, ASP.NET won't be happy receiving HTML markup because it will think that this some sort of XSS attack.

Comment: To fix the above stated by @Icarus you should HTMLEncode the text first, and decode it when you want to show it to the user(if thats the final goal)

Comment: Initially I got an error saying Http Violation .. Its working Fine after Encoding And Decoding.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use User Control to encapsulate your content

Visibility : You can use Visible property of your user control

Persistance : You can use EnableViewState property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Visibility and ViewState dont play well together in asp.net

Comment: Visible property in order to render visible your control, ViewState in order to persist your control; two different subjects

Comment: you can have persisted control in viewstate bu not visible for example

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, when you establish the visible property in the control, the viewstate is lost. The workaround for this is not using the visible property, but using style=display:none;

Comment: Thank you Andrei for your complement